# D365 FO / Odata error : unable to resolve the type name '' to an EdmType

Tags: powerbi, odata, x++, erp, dynamics-365-operations

I am making a PowerBI Report about time sheets from Dynamics Finance Operation but i can't see the "Hours" columns (1 column by day of the week, with a number of hours worked). It is an array with 7 days, made as an extended data type.

When I Query on SQL Server , i see the 7 fields Hours.

[SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl3Ar.png)

in Odata, it is not showing in Power BI or Excel with Odata from the data entity i created. i see all other fields , except the Hours fields (extended data type). I can also have the error "unable to resolve the type name '' to an EdmType"

I created a Public data entity from TSTimesheetLineEntity (the data entity exists but is not public), the field "Hours" that i can't reach is in the table TSTimesheetLineWeek. I also tried to only create a data entity from the table TSTimesheetlineWeek but i have the same issue.

[Extended Data Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phn6q.png)

[Hours parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAhgK.png)

[Data entity TSTimesheetLineEntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQv2D.png)

Any help would be appreciated, I am new on D365 :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `Hours` field is an array field. Those are not supported by OData. See [Array fields - Open Data Protocol (OData)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#array-fields):

> OData does not support array fields in entities. This must be taken into consideration when designing entities that will be used with OData.

This would require a customization. One option would be to add `Hour1-7` fields to the entity and add logic to the entity that populates those fields when the entity is called.